# Python:'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, zip, python-itertools

```
points 1 =[1219.5537056928035, [1318.8861439312564, 1214.6746106337268,
           1110.4630773361973, 1006.2515440386678, 902.0400107411383]]
```

For the above list, I want to create ordered pairs, by considering points 1[0] as X-axis and points 1[1] as Y-axis.
example:

```
[(1219.553,1318.88),(1219.553,1214.674), (1219.553,1110.465)...................   

list(zip(itertools.repeat(points1[0],points1[1])))
```

I am trying using zip, but getting error:

```
'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: You should try to make a numpy array of your list, by using ```np.asarray(points1)```

Comment: You can't have a space in your variable name, might want to edit the top line of code

Comment: Hi Simon, there is no space between variable name, while typing it happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) here.

```
list(itertools.product([points1[0]],points1[1]))
```

---

```
[(1219.5537056928035, 1318.8861439312564),
 (1219.5537056928035, 1214.6746106337268),
 (1219.5537056928035, 1110.4630773361973),
 (1219.5537056928035, 1006.2515440386678),
 (1219.5537056928035, 902.0400107411383)]
```

For the error you got. The signature of [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) is

```
itertools.repeat(object[, times])
```

Where `times` takes integers as an argument and you gave it a list.

Comment: @indu If the answer helped. You accept this as answer and upvote. Glad to help `;)`

Answer (score 1):

```
points1 =[1219.5537056928035, [1318.8861439312564, 1214.6746106337268,
           1110.4630773361973, 1006.2515440386678, 902.0400107411383]]

x = points1[0]
ys= points1[1]

print([ (x,y) for y in ys])
```

---

**output:**

```
[
 (1219.5537056928035, 1318.8861439312564), 
 (1219.5537056928035, 1214.6746106337268),
 (1219.5537056928035, 1110.4630773361973),
 (1219.5537056928035, 1006.2515440386678),
 (1219.5537056928035, 902.0400107411383)
]
```